# Program execution in java

Tags: java

I am trying to open an exe file, specificly the IndriRunQuery.exe which is one of the tools that offers the Lemur Indri package. When i use the command prompt i write the following command:

```
IndriRunQuery Queries.txt
```

With this, the editting of the queries that are included in Queries.txt (which is passed as a parameter in the above command) is starting.

Then after a descent amount of time has passed ,i write the following in order to save the results that are produced in a file named Results.txt:

```
 IndriRunQuery Queries.txt >Results.txt
```

My problem is that every time that i want to edit a file which contains queries
i need to do the same steps. i have 20 different query files to edit. I am trying to find a way to do it by using a java program but i can not figure it out.

I have used these lines of code but it doesnot work at all. 
Can anyone help me out with this?

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Indri\\Indri 5.8\\bin\\IndriRunQuery.exe", 
            "C:\\Users\\Πετρής\\Desktop\\TitlesRel.txt");
    builder.start();
    ProcessBuilder builder2 = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Indri\\Indri 5.8\\bin\\IndriRunQuery.exe", 
            "C:\\Users\\Πετρής\\Desktop\\TitlesRel.txt",">C:\\Users\\Πετρής\\Desktop\\resultsexample3.txt");

    builder2.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is as below:

```
// Create ProcessBuilder.
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
// Use command "notepad.exe" and open the file.
p.command("notepad.exe", "C:\\file.txt");
p.start();
```

Or

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```